# ember select change model property only on button click

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember `Select` that is bound to a property of the model in a modal dialog.

I want the model property to change only if the user clicks OK (and gets reverted if he clicks cancel).

How can I do that?

edit-session-modal.hbs:

```
{{#modal-dialog title='Change status (select empty to return to original status)' ok='save' close='closeModal'}}
    <form {{action 'ok' on='submit' target=view}}>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Status</label>
          {{view "select" content=sessionStatuses selection=model.status}}
        </div>
    </form>
{{/modal-dialog}}
```

controllers/edit-session-modal.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    close: function() {
      return this.send('closeModal');
    }
  },
  sessionStatuses: ['', 'SUCCESS', 'FAILURE', 'RUNNING'],
  selectedStatus: "model.status"
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by not binding the `model.status` property to `selection` property of `Ember.Select`, but use some kind of a buffer.

Let's say that your template look like this:

```
{{view "select" content=sessionStatuses selection=userSelection}}
```

And your controller should have following actions:

```
actions: {
  close: function() {
    this.set("selection", undefined); # or any other that should be default
    # everything else, like closing the modal
  },
  save: function() {
    this.set("model.status", this.get("selection"));
    # everything else, like saving the model
  }
}
```

#### EDIT after @Boaz reference

In @Boaz example there is no route defined for that controller. The solution turned out to be creating view object with `didInsertElement` as follows:

```
didInsertElement: function() { 
  modelStatus = this.get('controller').get('model.editedStatus');
  this.get('controller').set('selectedStatus', modelStatus); 
}
```

Comment: I can recommend ember-buffered-proxy for that: https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-buffered-proxy

Comment: @Jakub - I tried something similar - I got stuck initing this userSelection. Becuase controller stays persistent, it isn't updated on the second call of the modal dialog

Comment: You can set it to any default you want in `setupController` route hook. What do you think?

Comment: (just noticed you commented) the thing is that I have no route. all I do is showModal: function(name, model) {
      this.render(name, {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'modal',
        model: model
      }); 
in route/application.js

Comment: tried making an init action, but I can't figure out where to call it from

Comment: FUTURE REFERENCE - Got it! I have made a view with   didInsertElement : function(){
    this.get('controller').set('selectedStatus', this.get('controller').get(('model.editedStatus')));
  }

If you can please add it to your answer for completeness